# Biblatex @inbook syntax error

Tags: biblatex

an entry I used for two years doesn't work anymore (in fact, there are dozen of them who don't work anymore). Instead I got a syntax error message:

```
found "mph", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
```

It seems that all entries with a "booktitle" or "maintitle" field now have a problem... What may be wrong ?

```
@inbook{CabFon,
author = {Cécile Caby},
Gender = {sf},
title = {Fondation et naissance des ordres religieux},
shorttitle = {Fondation et naissance},
booktitle = {Mittelalterliche Orden und Klöster im Vergleich},
year = {2007},
editor = {G. Melville and A. Müller},
subtitle = {Remarques pour une étude comparée des ordres religieux au Moyen Âge},
booksubtitle = {Methodische Ansätze und Perspektiv},
series = {Vita Regularis Abhandlungen},
number = {34},
location = {Münster},
Keywords                 = {Cisterciens, Mémoire}
}
```

This is what I had before Caby, Cécile, « Fondation et naissance des ordres religieux, Remarques pour une étude comparée des ordres religieux au Moyen Âge », in : Mittelalter- liche Orden und Klöster im Vergleich, Methodische Ansätze und Perspektiv, sous la dir. de G. Melville et A. Müller, Münster, 2007, Vita Regularis Abhandlungen 34.

The lines used to load biblatex are those ones

```latex
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}
```

And the whole error message is

```
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.9 INFO - Logfile is 'Barth - Fiche - KD Â§ 75.blg'

INFO - Reading './Barth - Fiche - KD § 75.bcf' INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file '/mnt/E6A87F28A87EF701/Documents/Etudes/Z Outils/Bibliographie/Zbibtheologie.bib' for section 0 INFO - LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source '/mnt/E6A87F28A87EF701/Documents/Etudes/Z Outils/Bibliographie/Zbibtheologie.bib' ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/YhijtomnmR/Zbibtheologie.bib_5463.utf8, line 768, syntax error: found "mph", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@") INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

line 768 is the line of the "maintitle" field in my bibliography file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add all important information directly to the question. You can edit your own question and add what you posted in your comment to it.

Comment: Could you also include a minimal working example, the parts of your code that produce the problem (not just the bib-entry, also the lines loading `bibtex` or `biblatex` etc.)

Comment: There is no error in the entry you have shown above. Perhaps the error is earlier in your bib file. `biber` has become more picky recently with what it accents, so that may be the reason that things have worked in the past.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the entry shown: It compiles just fine for me. (You may want to check the `booksubtitle` field: "Perspektiv" sounds wrong, a short Google search suggests it should be "Perspektiven"). Note also that the entry shown here does not contain the letter combination `mph` that is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Sorry I thought I would receive an notification e-mail if someone answers, that's why I didn't check before... Thank you for the answers

Comment: okay in fact the problem was by another entry (but for a reason I quite don't get it stayed even when I desactivated the entry with %, and stayed also on documents where the entry was not used)

```LaTeX

@inbook{BarKDIV475,

author = {Karl Barth},

title = {Die Taufe als Begründung des christlichen Lebens (\emph{§~75 / Fragment})},

booktitle = {Die Lehre der Versöhnung. Das christliche Leben} \emph{(KD IV/4)}},

year = {1991},

series = {Studienausgabe},

number = {30},

publisher = {Theologischer Verlag},

location = {Zürich}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The entry `CabFon` shown in the question is syntactically well-formed and will not raise any Biber errors. But in the comments you posted the following entry

```
@inbook{BarKDIV475,
  author    = {Karl Barth},
  title     = {Die Taufe als Begründung des christlichen Lebens (\emph{§~75 / Fragment})},
  booktitle = {Die Lehre der Versöhnung. Das christliche Leben} \emph{(KD IV/4)}},
  year      = {1991},
  series    = {Studienausgabe},
  number    = {30},
  publisher = {Theologischer Verlag},
  location  = {Zürich},
}
```

Indeed that entry will cause errors because the `}` after `Leben` in the `booktitle` closes the field, so that the `\emph{(KD IV/4)}}` is kept dangling.

You probably want

```
@inbook{BarKDIV475,
  author    = {Karl Barth},
  title     = {Die Taufe als Begründung des christlichen Lebens (\emph{§~75 / Fragment})},
  booktitle = {Die Lehre der Versöhnung. Das christliche Leben \emph{(KD IV/4)}},
  year      = {1991},
  series    = {Studienausgabe},
  number    = {30},
  publisher = {Theologischer Verlag},
  location  = {Zürich},
}
```

---

It has nothing to do with your problem, but you may want to consider changing

```
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}[0]{\addcomma\addspace}
```

to

```
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\mkbibemph}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

`\mkbibemph` is the version of `\emph` that should be used in a `biblatex` formatting context. The `\addspace` in `\addcomma\addspace` has no benefit over `\space`, so all idiomatic expressions like this in the `biblatex` kernel and standard styles use `\addcomma\space`.

Comment: Oh you're all right that was the problem!  I still don't get why it prevented so much other entries (including CabFon) to work... But that's alright!
Thankk you once again, and thank you for both correction about "Perspektiven" and \mkbibemph!

Comment: I should close the topic, shouldn't I?

Comment: @Greg Low-level parsing errors like this can mean that Biber basically has to give up trying to read the rest of the file, since it can not know how braces should match.

Comment: @Greg If the answer helped you, you should consider accepting it, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. That will mark the question as resolved.

Comment: @moewe Isn't Biber missing some kind of Artificial Intelligence to understand that this is just a "stupid" human error that should cause no compilation error :) ?